# sed remove lines in range

Tags: sed, xml

I have an xml file. I am trying to remove only the blank lines from a range of lines. In this example I want to check lines 55-57 and remove any blank lines.

This needs to be done in a shell script over multiple files that are all xml. This is a RHEL 7 system.

I tried using `sed`, but wasn't able to strip the empty lines out.

I have written statements that get the appropriate line numbers, they are stored as vars in the shell script (`start_line`, `finish_line`)

Example File:

```
1.
2. 
3. <Test></Test>
        .
        .
        .
55.
56.
57.<!-- keep the comment -->
58. <KeepTag></KeepTag>
```

What can I do to remove the blank lines only from range 55-57?

Comment: Please be careful parsing XML with line-based tools, unless you know FOR SURE that the XML format will remain unchanged from your example.

Comment: Thanks for the head up, it will remain unchanged, I insert it with the script, I am writing a removal piece

Comment: `sed`editor can do this easily : `sed -E '55,57{/\S/!d;}'`

Answer (score 3, accepted):

You could do this easily with [awk](/questions/tagged/awk) :

```
awk 'FNR>=55 && FNR<=57 && NF==0{next}1' file
```

This uses the usual `awk` shorthand notation that a `1` in the "main program body" (i.e. outside rule-specific code in `{ ... }`) means "print the current line including any modifications performed by rules".

However, it bypasses this `print` command by issuing the `next` command *if* the following criteria apply:

- The line number is between (and including) 55 and 57 (condition: `FNR>=55 && FNR<=57`, with `FNR` being the per-file line-number -- as opposed to `NR`, the global line number, which can differ if you use `awk` to process multiple files in one call!)

  and
- the line contains no text, indicated by `NF`, the number of content fields, being zero.

Because of this "bypassing", the output generated by `awk` will exclude empty lines if they fall in the specified line range.

Comment: Syntax error, on >

Comment: OOps, typo fixed

Comment: This removed the comments as well. I need to keep anything else and ONLY remove the blank lines.

Comment: Post edited accordingly

Comment: I ran the update, it still strips everything. The comments need to stay. and so do the tags. This is to ONLY REMOVE BLANK LINES

Comment: Edited in the meanwhile, please test again

Comment: I think something like `awk 'NR>=55 && NR<=57 && NF==0 {next} 1' file` might be what the OP wants ...

Comment: @AdminBee that is exactly what I needed, thank you!

Comment: @AdminBee post your answer so I can accept it

Comment: We work together to gave you this command. No need a duplicate

Comment: @EnterStrandman I will incorporate some explanation into this answer; you can accept this, then.

Answer (score 2):

With sed, you can do it with address range

```
sed '55,57{/^$/d}' file
```

this will apply d command (delete) on selected empty line (/^$/) between line 55 and 57 (55,57). I am not able to test it, but I think you must add a ';' after the d command in macos.

use

```
sed -i '55,57{/^$/d;}' file
```

if you want to modify your file locally

Answer (score 1):

With `sed`:

```
start_line=55
finish_line=57
sed "$start_line","$finish_line"'{/^$/d;}' file
```

Comment: tried this, it did nothing, sticking with the awk from @AdminBee